# Loading select options from a service in a directive before model binding angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I'm trying to create a directive to load select items(from server) for the lists that I need using a Key for each list, but it seams that model is bound before the items get a chance to load, and the desired item is not get selected, any suggestion?

**Services:**

```
arsinServices.factory('GeneralProperties', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/GeneralProperties/');
}]);
```

**Directive:**

```
directives.directive('ngarGpSelect', ['GeneralProperties', 
function (GeneralProperties) {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $attrs, GeneralProperties) {
            $scope.gpItems =  GeneralProperties.query({ key: $attrs.gpkey });
        },
        templateUrl: '/templates/gp-select.html',
        require: 'ngModel',
    }
}]);
```

**Template:**

```
<select  ng-options="gp.Index as gp.Name for gp in gpItems"></select>
```

**Contoller:**

```
arsinControllers.controller('RequestEditCtrl', ['$scope', 'request',
    function ($scope, request) {
        $scope.request = request;
}
```

**View:**

```
<ngar-gp-select gpKey="RequestType" ng-model="request.RequestTypeIndex"/>
```

**Update**
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLsns) thanks to @Nix.

**Update 2:**
If I replace the line which set gpItems in directive controller whith something like this:

```
$scope.gpItems =   [{ Index: 1, Name: 'option1' }, { Index: 2, Name: 'option2' }, { Index: 3, Name: 'option3' }];
```

It will work as expected, and the item get selected.

Comment: fiddle... cough... fiddle.  It will dramatically help response times.

Comment: @Nix I'm working on it ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yLsns/  here you go... it worked for me so you have something else going on.  @VahidND .

Comment: @Nix Thanks for the fiddle but it's not working for me, Nick is not selected when I run it.

Comment: see below.. the fiddle works, but I dont really see a question here?

Answer (score 1):

You have yet to really show an "issue"...  I dont understand what you are trying to do but if you initialize `$scope.request` in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsHH7/) Nick will be selected.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.request = {
        RequestTypeIndex: 1
    }
    $scope.RequestType = 1
}
```

Then in your directive you need to use the promise(although your example should work):

```
function (GeneralProperties) {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $attrs, GeneralProperties) {
            GeneralProperties.query({ key: $attrs.gpkey }).then(function(data){
                $scope.gpItems =  data
            }, function(error){
                alert(error);
            })
        },
        templateUrl: '/templates/gp-select.html',
        require: 'ngModel',
    }
}]);
```

Comment: You're right I considered `$scope.RequestType = 1` as the initializer for the select mistakenly. please see my updated question.

Comment: Your answer and fiddle reassured me that it should work this way and made me double check everything and led me to the answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a callback from the `query`:

```
GeneralProperties.query({ key: $attrs.gpkey }, function(data) {
    $scope.gpItems = data;
});
```

Comment: Didn't work, I get the infamous `<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>` selected.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I located the problem, it was because of items from my service. the Index property was of type `string` instead of `int`, I changed the type in my server side interface and it worked. I have had found similar cases in SO mentioning this but I overlooked them. I hope it will help someone else.